# Error (10536): VHDL Loop Statement error at counts.vhd(25): loop must terminate within 10,000 iterations

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I am trying to make an elevator using while loops. but i keep getting the same  error for the loops

```
  library ieee;
 use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.all;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
 entity counts is
Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;     -- input clock
      S,NF : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
          RESET: in STD_LOGIC;
          Output : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0));    
 end counts;

   architecture Behavioral of counts is
signal count: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0):="000";
begin


process (CLK, RESET,NF)
     begin
 if (RESET = '1') then
   count <= "000";
    elsif (CLK'Event and CLK = '1' and RESET = '0') then
       if (S < NF and S > "000") then
          count <= S;
countup: while (count < NF and NF <= "111" ) loop
 count <= count + '1';
 Output <=  count;
 end loop countup;

       elsif (S > NF and S > "111") then  
 count <= S;
countdown: while (count > NF and NF >= "000") loop
 count <= count - '1';
 Output <=  count;
  end loop countdown;
  else 
 count <= S;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

-- display count
Output <=  count;

end Behavioral;
```

i don't know why i keep getting this error but it is the only error standing in the way of my project. the error is shown below.

Error (10536): VHDL Loop Statement error at counts.vhd(25): loop must terminate within 10,000 iterations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to show one cycle of 8 bit LFSR with VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016926/trying-to-show-one-cycle-of-8-bit-lfsr-with-vhdl)

Comment: Note that output should have the relationship `if S >= NF then output <= S - NF; else output <= NF - S; end if;`, the absolute difference between S and NF which loses the direction your elevator should move. You have multiple drivers for output, the unlabelled process statement and the equivalent process for the concurrent assignment statement.

Comment: Signal updates are scheduled until the next wait statement (or end of a process). Your signal `count` doesn't change in the while loop, thus the condition is never met and an infinite loop is created by your code. This infinite loop is stopped by your tool after 10.000 iterations.